# tmux - hide scroll position indicator

Tags: tmux

Is there a way to hide the scroll position indicator or move it to the bottom?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about hiding this while scrolling? Or is your question about how to get out of scroll mode (which would remove it)?

Comment: I would like to hide the scroll position indicator in copy mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since tmux 3.2:

```
* Add a copy-mode -H flag to hide the position marker in the top right.
```

Comment: How did you configure tmux to use this flag? Related question from me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/720433/how-to-enter-tmux-copy-mode-always-with-the-h-option