# How to enter tmux copy-mode always with the -H option?

Tags: tmux

I want to hide the position indicator shown in copy-mode.

[image: tmux copy-mode position indicator]

Tmux supports this with the `-H` option.

> -H hides the position indicator in the top right.

But how do I apply this to my Tmux configuration? Do I have to override all key combinations that start the copy-mode, like scrolling and `[`? Or is there another way to make Tmux always use the `-H` option?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I started by extracting all the key bindings into a file.

```
tmux list-keys > keybindings.txt
```

In this file I searched for all bindings that call `copy-mode` and that don't already use `-H`.

I added the `-H` option to these bindings and added them to my personal configuration.

```
bind-key -T prefix [ copy-mode -H
bind-key -T prefix PPage copy-mode -u -H
bind-key -T root MouseDrag1Pane if-shell -F "#{||:#{pane_in_mode},#{mouse_any_flag}}" "send-keys -M" "copy-mode -M -H"
bind-key -T root WheelUpPane if-shell -F "#{||:#{pane_in_mode},#{mouse_any_flag}}" "send-keys -M" "copy-mode -e -H"
```